# Closed embedding of the half line in a non-compact manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, submanifold

I am trying to do an exercise for some time now that is the following :

> Let $M$ be a connected Hausdorff non-compact paracompact $C^r$ manifold. Then there is a closed $C^r$ embedding of the half line $[0,\infty[$ into $M$.

I have tried two approaches to this

1. I consider a compact exhaustion of $M$ and try and create this map by considering injective paths between points in $K_i-intK_i$ and such. Problem for this I can't control the injectivity of the different paths.

2.I consider a chart that has no finite subcover , I can assume this has countable subcover tought since $M$ is secound-countable. Now I try usnig these charts and open sets construct path betwenn the points myself that are injective, but I always run into the same problem that I don't seem to be able to control the injectivity for the different paths.

The two approaches are kinda similar but I don't know what else could be done.

Any help with this is aprecciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe try a chain of disks $U_i$ going off to infinity with $U_i$ intersecting only $U_{i-1}$ and $U_{i+1}$? Map $[i-1,i]$ into $U_i$, making sure everything patches smoothly.